Composer class not found error on class alias in Laravel
Problem intro:

I'm implementing a custom caching solution that utilizes a file store but still allows tagging.
For this, I've installed some packages which are irrelevant to the question (I do mention them below). The problem occurs with my facade implementation.
I've created a ServiceProvider (which is registered in Laravel 11's providers.php) for this implementation, where I bind a class from the composer package to taggable-cache. Here, I've also used the AliasLoaded to register the TCache alias for my Facade class.
namespace App\Providers;

use AlternativeLaravelCache\Store\AlternativeFileCacheStoreWithLocks;
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TaggableCacheServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
        $this->app->bind('taggable-cache', function() {
            /** @var AlternativeFileCacheStoreWithLocks $store */
            $store = app('cache')->store('file');

            return $store;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $aliasLoader = AliasLoader::getInstance();

        $aliasLoader->alias('TCache', \App\Facades\TaggableCacheFacade::class);
    }
}

Of course, this comes with the aforementioned Facade, which is quite simple
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class TaggableCacheFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor(): string
    {
        return 'taggable-cache';
    }
}

Unsure if related to the issue

I ran into an issue where PhpStorm was unable to 'recognize' the TCache class. To fix this I installed the package barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper. This allowed me to generate an _ide_helper.php file and fixes the issue of PhpStorm not recognizing the class.
Actual errors

After setting this up and confirming it works as intended I tried running composer install to test if the commands I added in the "post-update-cmd" hook for the ide-helper package worked, except I now keep running into the following error:
// The command:

composer i

// Output:

Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package sinergi/browser-detector is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Error 

  Class "TCache" not found

  at app/Services/RouteService.php:446
    442▕      * @return array
    443▕      */
    444▕     private function getAcceptedRouteParameters(): array
    445▕     {
  ➜ 446▕         return TCache::tags(CacheTag::ROUTES->value)->rememberForever(
    447▕             "accepted_route_parameters",
    448▕             function () {
    449▕                 return [
    450▕                     'locale' => ['locale'],

  1   app/Services/RouteService.php:39
      App\Services\RouteService::getAcceptedRouteParameters()

  2   [internal]:0
      App\Services\RouteService::__construct()

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Before I ran composer install everything was working as expected, but now I keep getting the Class not found errors, both in the console and the front end of my website, keep in mind that this was working fine before I ran composer install.
I tried running other commands, like composer dump-autoload to see if that would help. I also removed the scripts from "post-update-cmd" and ran composer install again to no avail. So I am now unable to run any commands, also php artisan commands.
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?
Project details:



Package
Version




PHP
8.3.8


laravel/framework
11.15.0


statamic/cms
5.13.0


barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
3.0.0


swayok/alternative-laravel-cache
6.1.16


swayok/cache-filesystem-adapter
1.3.2




Full error log
For completeness sake I will add the full error log to the question.
[2024-07-11 06:45:14] local.ERROR: Class "TCache" not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class \"TCache\" not found at /usr/share/nginx/html/app/Services/RouteService.php:446)
[stacktrace]
#0 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/Services/RouteService.php(39): App\\Services\\RouteService->getAcceptedRouteParameters()
#1 [internal function]: App\\Services\\RouteService->__construct()
#2 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(983): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()
#3 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(815): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#4 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1046): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#5 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(324): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#6 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(931): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#7 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(815): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#8 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1046): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#9 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(751): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#10 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1028): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#11 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(124): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#12 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(46): app()
#13 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider->boot()
#14 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#15 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#16 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#17 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(690): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#18 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1119): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#19 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1100): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootProvider()
#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->Illuminate\\Foundation\\{closure}()
#21 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1099): array_walk()
#22 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->boot()
#23 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(316): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\BootProviders->bootstrap()
#24 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(470): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith()
#25 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(194): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#26 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1203): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#27 /usr/share/nginx/html/artisan(13): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->handleCommand()
#28 {main}
"} 


Update to add.
After some more testing, I have confirmed that it has to do with the class aliases. If I call the underlying Facade (TaggableCacheFacade) instead of its alias (TCache), it does work.
However I am convinced I have the correct understanding of registering class aliases in Laravel 11, so any help would be appreciated.

Have you tried php artisan config:clear ?

Well yes @AndriiSukhoi but as mentioned in the question, all commands fail with the error described above.

Just remove the alias(). No need.

Need for an alias depends on your use-case @puklipo, we've been using a similar implementation for a while now, so we want to keep it the same even when upgrading Laravel, so for us there is a need.
